# JxBrowser 6.13 : how to load a Plugin in Chromium

Tags: plugins, jxbrowser

We're trying to display a website via JxBrowser but this webpage says that:
one of the following plugin must be used : Silverlight, Html5, MPEG-DASH in MSE

The webPage in question is generated by MediaSite

I've read that Silverlight is not supported, but what about the others? and how to load them through JxBrowser  ???

Some help would be great, even just hints to know where to search..!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I've read that Silverlight is not supported**
Yes, Silverlight  is not supported since JxBrowser 6.4 due to the fact that Chromium engine dropped the NPAPI plugin support at all.

**but what about the others? and how to load them through JxBrowser ???**
As far as I know HTML5 is not a Chrome plugin and is WEB standart is supported by JxBrowser by default including HTML5 audio/video.
JxBrowser supports regular Google Chrome plugins, which were installed in your system through installer. If you properly install such Chrome plugin in your system and Google Chrome recognizes this plugin, then it is expected that JxBrowser recognizes and uses this plugin as well when it is necessary.

Please note, than displaying multimedia content in JxBrowser might be different comparing to Google Chrome, due to the fact that Chromium doesn't have some codecs enabled by default. Please take a look at the [article](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013050-mp3-mp4-h-264) for details.